# Is there a way to sort the config.xml file and update package.json?

Tags: cordova, npm

I use the `Cordova CLI` to prepare, build and run my project.

I am often in the case where, my `config.xml` is updated by any version of my plugins and any version of android and ios platforms.

I understand that it is the way that `NPM` works, in respect with `semver`.

But `config.xml` is always all messed up, the order of the lines are never respected, neither are predictable (not in alpabetic order for example).

So I wondering if there is a way to ensure that the order will always be the same?

Is it possible for a hook to manipulate the `config.xml` itself? And in which phase of the lifecycle of `Cordova`?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? This happens every day and is a real pain when working in a team because of all the unnecessary merge conflicts.

Comment: Unfortunately no :(. I've gotten used to to only watch package.json for versions of engine and plugins and to watch config.xml for all other type of configuration. But other dev are still bothered by new version of the config.xml with no change but the order of the lines...